# Copy/move files with perl

Tags: perl, copy, move

I have a problem with copying/moving files with perl.
I want to move a directory with sub-directories into an other directory. Both are given in absolute paths.
What I do is:

```
system("mv $source $destination")
```

where `$source` and `$destination` are my source and destination folders.

I also tried it with:

```
system("cp -r $source $destination")
```

and with all possible options, but every time I try it gives me the following output:

```
sh: line 1: $destination: is a directory
```

where the `$destination` is my destination path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're giving the mv and/or cp command(s) the wrong arguments. Which is in no way whatsoever a Perl problem.

Comment: I suspect your `$source` is it a directory or file?

Comment: both
    `$source`
and 
    `$destination` are folder in format of "User/Desktop/somefolder/
So what would be the right arguments? I tried to read the variables with print() and it gives the right output

Comment: I bet `$source` has a newline at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of executing

```
cp -r source destination
```

You are executing

```
cp -r source
destination
```

`$source` appears to contain a trailing newline. Adding `chomp($source);` is probably the correct fix.

---

By the way, you aren't building your shell command correctly. You should be using the following:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $shell_cmd = shell_quote("cp", "-r", "--", $source, $destination);
system($shell_cmd);
```

That said, there's no reason to involve a shell at all, so you should be using the following:

```
system("cp", "-r", "--", $source, $destination)
```